# what's the meaning of the result of var_dump (object)?

Tags: php

var_dump(object) returns: object()#1 
I really want to know what's the difference between object()#1, object()#2, and object()#3. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i have this [exemple](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/03ba0319017747f079ad494ff81d1239cc740bc2) , i think its like an `id` of each object, because i didn't see any of it repeated twice

Answer (score 6):

For objects with identical information (same class, same properties) it allows to determine whether they are the same instance. For example:

```
$a = new DateTime();
$b = $a; // Link to same instance
$c = clone $a; // Create a new copy
var_dump($a, $b, $c);
```

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2020-08-15 19:23:39.016441"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "Europe/Amsterdam"
}
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2020-08-15 19:23:39.016441"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "Europe/Amsterdam"
}
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2020-08-15 19:23:39.016441"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "Europe/Amsterdam"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply put:

- #1 means `first object to be declared`
- #2: second object to be declared
- #3: etc.

The behavior is slightly different if one object has been reinitialized (re-assigned) in the course of the script.

Example

```
class MyClass
{
}

$obj1 = new MyClass;
$obj2 = new stdClass;
$obj3 = new MyClass;
$obj3 = (object) [];

var_dump($obj3);
var_dump($obj1);
var_dump($obj4);
var_dump($obj2);
```

Result:

```
object(MyClass)#3 (0) {
}
object(MyClass)#1 (0) {
}
object(stdClass)#4 (0) {
}
object(stdClass)#2 (0) {
}
```

As you can see, no matter the order of the `var_dump`, `#number` tells the order in which the object where instanciated.

Comment: declared where ? can you explain more, with reference i will be grateful

Comment: Yes, I've added an example to explain what I wanted to say.

Answer (score 1):

`var_dump` dumps information about a variable. This function displays structured information about one or more expressions that include its type and value. Arrays and objects are explored recursively with values indented to show structure.

`object()#1 ,object()#2,and object()#3 are the different object values inside a nested object which have been evaluated and given an id by var_dump`

Read more here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

**Edit 2**

It seems `Object()#number` is the order in which it finds some key/value pair inside a nested object. If an object doesn't contain any key/value pair and just contains another object (with key/value pair), that inner object is evaluated first and the #number is given accordingly. The outer object is evaluated last.

Also, the `Object()#number` is carried over if a different object is evaluated. The `Object()#number` starts from where it ended in the first object

Here is an example. This code will decode the JSON and dump the output of the object

```
<?php
$a= '{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}';

$b ='{
    "entry1": {
        "entry2": {
            "title": 2,
            "entry3": {
                "title": 4,
                "title" : 5
            }
        }
    }
}';


$json1 = json_decode($a);
$json2 = json_decode($b);


var_dump($json1);
var_dump($json2);
```

**Output**

```
object(stdClass)#6 (1) {
  ["glossary"]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(16) "example glossary"
    ["GlossDiv"]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
      ["title"]=>
      string(1) "S"
      ["GlossList"]=>
      object(stdClass)#5 (1) {
        ["GlossEntry"]=>
        object(stdClass)#3 (7) {
          ["ID"]=>
          string(4) "SGML"
          ["SortAs"]=>
          string(4) "SGML"
          ["GlossTerm"]=>
          string(36) "Standard Generalized Markup Language"
          ["Acronym"]=>
          string(4) "SGML"
          ["Abbrev"]=>
          string(13) "ISO 8879:1986"
          ["GlossDef"]=>
          object(stdClass)#4 (2) {
            ["para"]=>
            string(72) "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook."
            ["GlossSeeAlso"]=>
            array(2) {
              [0]=>
              string(3) "GML"
              [1]=>
              string(3) "XML"
            }
          }
          ["GlossSee"]=>
          string(6) "markup"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
object(stdClass)#10 (1) {
  ["entry1"]=>
  object(stdClass)#9 (1) {
    ["entry2"]=>
    object(stdClass)#7 (2) {
      ["title"]=>
      int(2)
      ["entry3"]=>
      object(stdClass)#8 (1) {
        ["title"]=>
        int(5)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: he meaning with **System doesn't let me submit** that stackoverflow dont let him submit because the number of character of his question didn't reach the require

Comment: what is meaning **are the different values inside the array or object** ? can you give an exemple ?

Comment: Thanks Chilarai.  Could you share a little more about the difference between object()#1 ,object()#2,and object()#3? I really appreciate it!

Comment: in the manual they didn't mentionnad what `#` meaning

Comment: @GNassro, let me know

Comment: @ToffeeConmigo, I have updated the example. Let me know if it answers your question

Comment: so as i see, $json1 and $json2 they are two objects separately, but $json2 start(#7) from the end(#6) of the $json1. emm interesting

Comment: @Chilarai Thanks for the example! I kind of get your point!

Comment: While this is a reasonable speculation, it's not actually `var_dump` that's assigning these numbers; they are an internal identifier assigned when the object is created.

Answer (score 0):

From a user's point of view, the number is an arbitrary ID which can be used to see if two variables point to the same object; it is unique across all objects in a program, regardless of class and scope.

It can be retrieved directly using [the `spl_object_id` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-id.php). For instance:

```
class Test {}

$test1 = new Test;
$test1_id = spl_object_id( $test1 );
$test2 = new Test;
$test2_id = spl_object_id( $test2 );

var_dump( $test1 );
var_dump( $test2 );
var_dump( $test1_id );
var_dump( $test2_id );
```

Will output something like this:

```
object(Test)#1 (0) {
}
object(Test)#2 (0) {
}
int(1)
int(2)
```

The actual number should not be relied on as having any meaning, but in practice each object created is assigned a sequential ID, resetting at the start of each execution (HTTP request, or script invocation).

To give a very quick technical explanation, inside the definition of `var_dump`, this is the line that produces the output:

```
php_printf("%sobject(%s)#%d (%d) {\n", COMMON, ZSTR_VAL(class_name), Z_OBJ_HANDLE_P(struc), myht ? zend_array_count(myht) : 0);
```

The `Z_OBJ_HANDLE_P(struc)` macro expands roughly to `(*struc).value.obj->handle` - it is looking up the `handle` member from the C struct representing the object. That is initialised in a function called `zend_objects_store_put` which has this line:

```
handle = EG(objects_store).top++;
```

`EG` stands for "Execution Global", so this ultimately says "increment a counter in a per-execution store, and use that as the `handle` for the new object".

Which is why my example above, run without any other code, will give IDs of 1 and 2: the first two items to be added to the store during that execution.